# Receive request and send response in netty

Tags: netty

I have server like this:

```
//...
ServerBootstrap networkServer = new ServerBootstrap();
networkServer
  .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
  .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
  .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
  .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE))
  .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
          ChannelPipeline p = channel.pipeline();
          p.addLast(requestHandler);
        }
      });
// ...
```

And request handler like this:

```
@Sharable
@Component
public class RequestHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RequestHandler.class);

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object obj) {
  // (1)  ctx.write(obj);

  ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) obj;
  byte[] out = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
  try {
    int i = 0;
    while (in.readableBytes() > 0) {
      out[i++] = in.readByte();
    }

    Sproto.SProto msg = Sproto.SProto.parseFrom(out);

    Sproto.SProto response = Sproto.SProto.newBuilder()
      .setStatusCode(Common.ConfirmCodeStatus.OK)
      .setConnectResponse(Player.ConnectResponse.newBuilder())
      .build();

  // (2)   ctx.write(response);
  // (3)   ctx.write(obj);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
  }
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
  ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
  logger.error(cause.getMessage(), cause);
  ctx.close();
}
```

When I'm just sending back request by:

```
// (1)  ctx.write(obj);
```

it works perfectly!

But when I'm trying to send the protobuf response after parsing request:

```
// (2)   ctx.write(response);
```

or just send back the request:

```
// (3)   ctx.write(obj);
```

it doesn't work! I don't see this response on client side.

What's wrong here?
What's the proper way to read message, do some logic and send new response to client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pipeline is initialized in the `ChannelInitializer` with only one handler: your `requestHandler`

This channel is an `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` with any defined type so it handles `Object` type. So, when a packet (`ByteBuf`) is received, your handler is correctly called.

Then when you call `write( object )` (and you should probably called `writeAndFlush()`), the argument is send to the pipeline to be handled. If the argument is a `ByteBuf`, the data will be written to the channel connexion as expected. But if not, like in your case where object is an instance of protobuf message, you need an outbound handler into the pipeline to convert this kind of object to a `ByteBuf`.

Netty provides an implementation of a [Protobuf encoder/decoder handlers](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/protobuf/ProtobufEncoder.html) that you can add on your pipeline. But you can also extends [`ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.html) and write you own way to serialize a protobuf message.

In your specific case, your pipeline should be something like:

- an out-bound handler which handles protobuf message, converts it into ByteBuf and sends it downstream on pipeline
- an in-bound handler which handles ByteBuf, converts it into a protobuf message and send this message upstream on pipeline
- an inbound handler which handles protobuf message and do some action (like sending a response)

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like it works, but when I'm converting response in out-bound handler and send it (ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(proto.toByteArray()))) I don't see this response on client. But when I'm stopping server instance, I receive this response on client side immediately. Why so?

Comment: Just need to write last byte '\n' and everything works like a charm! Thanks